# Using linux, how can I create a device file outside of the /dev directory that will give me permission to open and read it?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I am using linux kernel 3.8, ubuntu 13.04, I am curious if there is a way to do this. Also, I would like to know if there is some generic reason for why this doesn't work for me. Thanks.

Comment: If you've run a `mknod` and couldn't open the device, it's possible that it's on a filesystem mounted with the `nodev` option. You should really say what you tried and what error message you got.

Comment: It's also possible that the device driver you are working with is an older one which does not use the correct functions to register itself with udev.  More information on the nature of your problem would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Device files are created with `mknod`. Permissions and owner can be changed with `chmod` and `chown` respectively. If the device file already exists, you may want to create a symbolic link  to it instead using `ln -s`.